# Start a Gif on Hover

Tags: php, html, css, gif

I cannot figure out how to make my button start a gif while hovered and if its not hovered - it goes back to the previous background, and again on hover its start a gif from the starting position.
What i get is a gif constantly playing and on hover I get a random position (because the gif is playing constantly)

CSS

```
.gradient-button {
    /* Text Styles */
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Dark Purple Background by default */
    background: #282828;

    /* Shadow Effect */
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

    /* Transition for Hover Effect */
    transition: background 1s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gradient-button:hover {
    /* Hover Effect: GIF Background */
    background: url('./gifs/nastronke.gif') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: fill;

    /* Hover Effect: Lift Button */
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.gradient-button:hover::before {
    opacity: 0; /* Remove the overlay on hover */
}
```

HTML/PHP

```
<?php
                session_start();
                if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
                    echo '<a href="../logout.php" class="gradient-button">LOGOUT</a>';
                } else {
                    echo '<a href="../login.php" class="gradient-button">LOGIN</a>';
                }
                ?>
```

Any Ideas how Can i fix it?

Start gif on hover (stop at the end), stop while not hovered, then start from the beggining on hover.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have an anim gif on a link and play it on hover and reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752500/how-to-have-an-anim-gif-on-a-link-and-play-it-on-hover-and-reset)

Answer (score 1):

1. **Prepare Images:** You need two images: a static image (e.g., a single
   frame of the GIF to show when not hovered) and the GIF itself.
2. **JavaScript to Swap Images:** Use JavaScript to change the src
   attribute of an img tag or the background-image of a button when
   it's hovered over and when the hover ends.

Here's how you can adjust your current setup to include JavaScript functionality. Since your button seems to be styled as a link (`<a>` tag), you'll need to slightly adjust your approach to use a `div` or similar element that can have its background changed dynamically. However, for simplicity, I'll demonstrate how to swap images for an  tag, and you can adapt this to your needs.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="gradient-button" id="animatedButton">LOGIN</a>
```

**CSS**
Your CSS stays mostly the same, but you'll remove the **`background`** property change from **`.gradient-button:hover`** since we'll handle the hover effect with JavaScript.

**JS**

```
<script> document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var button = document.getElementById('animatedButton');

button.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    // Change to animated GIF on hover
    this.style.backgroundImage = "url('./gifs/nastronke.gif')";
});

button.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    // Change back to static image when not hovered
    this.style.backgroundImage = "url('./path/to/your/static/image.jpg')";
}); }); </script>
```

Remember to replace `'./path/to/your/static/image.jpg'` with the actual path to your static image and adjust the paths as needed for your setup.

Comment: Now when hovered just shadow shows up, there is no static.png and gid (the path is correct and I added the static.png)